# pagination for sorted table

Tags: mysql, pagination, paging

I try to make an efficient pagination. I have many tables with a lot of records. The biggest one has currently around 40000 records and will increase in the future. The tables have structures like this (eg):

```
order | type | item | price | quantity | packingunit | totalquantity
```

The tables are sortable by all displayed columns and of course they all have an ID which is also primary key and auto increment.

The problem is, that the queries will be slower and slower with the increasing amount of data. Currently the query looks like (eg):

```
... LIMIT 10000, 25
```

I want to get rid of OFFSET and find a faster way to get the results for each page.

I read a couple of blogs and also here on stackoverflow about this issue. There are ways to achieve an efficient pagination with

```
... WHERE id > 10000 LIMIT 25
```

But this only works when you sort the tables by the ID. And as I mentioned, my tables are sortable by each column. I thought about reading the IDs (after sorting) in a cache and query always the 25 IDs to be displayed at the called page, but this seems to be also a not very efficient way.

Does anyone has an idea, how to solve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I doubt any human in their right mind would browse through 400 pages. The would stop at 40 at most.

So it makes me think that the only user for such a deep pagination is a search engine. Therefore I would suggest to have two pagination systems. 
By default it orders by id, and allows flipping through all pages till the end using `WHERE id > xxx` trick.

But as soon as any other field is used for sorting, pagination stops at some reasonable page number and says "too many results found, please refine your search".

Comment: No, that is not an option. But thank you for your input. I already have a part of a solution that I will post as answer too.